# How to simultaneously remove and add data to a data store?

Tags: alloy

I am creating a simple model of a network. The network contains nodes. Each node has a data store. Nodes send data, from their data store, to other nodes.

```
sig Node { 
    data: Data -> Time,
    send: Data -> Node -> Time 
}
```

Suppose node n sends data d to node n' during the time period t - t':

```
n.send.t' = n.send.t + d -> n'
```

The data store for node n' is updated with d:

```
n'.data.t' = n'.data.t + d
```

Since node n has processed the data (i.e., sent the data), n *removes* d from its data store:

```
n.data.t' = n.data.t - d
```

Suppose, during the same time period, another node N has sent node n the same data d. That results in *adding* d to n's data store:

```
n.data.t' = n.data.t + d
```

Yikes! There is a contradiction:

```
n.data.t' = n.data.t - d
n.data.t' = n.data.t + d
```

There are no satisfying instances. What to do? How do I deal with a node that removes d from its data store while simultaneously adding d to its data store?

Comment: What happens if several other nodes send the same data d to n in the same time period ? If you need to have many occurence of d in the data store of n then you have to refine your model. This refinement will ultimately also answer your current question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define n.data.t' in terms of n.data.t and n'.send.t for all other nodes n', including n.

Comment: Hello @Daniel Jackson I think you are saying that the data in node n at time t' is the data at time t minus d plus the set of data sent to n from other nodes, i.e., n.data.t' = n.data.t - d + {d: Data | d in Node.send.t.n} Is that what you're saying?